# How is the canvas rendered

Tags: html, image-processing, canvas

When using the canvas control in html5 and drawing a pixel like so:

```
var id = ctx3.createImageData(1, 1); // only do this once per page
var d = id.data;   

//define a white dot
d[0] = 255; // r;
d[1] = 255; // g;
d[2] = 255; // b;
d[3] = 255; // a;

ctx3.putImageData(id, x, y);
```

Is the data sent to the client and then drawn onto the canvas or is the canvas already drawn onto  on the server and then rendered to client?

Comment: `JavaScript` is always executed on the client.

Comment: OK, that was what I thought too. But just wanted to confirm. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas is an Html5 DOM object, and is manipulated using java script.  Java script is always executed on the client.

So, to answer your question, the code to manipulate the canvas comes from the server, but is executed and rendered by the browser.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Getting my haircut. Thanks